# Page that self-edits

Tags: php, html, file, ckeditor, edit

i want to create an html file with CKEDITOR included, and when the edit is finished, the html file gets correctly modified.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Editable</title>
    // Adds CKEDITOR
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    // Simple DIV with in-line CKEDITOR

    <div id="editable1" contenteditable="true">
        <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
        <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.
    </div>

<script>

//Adds the editor
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable' );

//When focus is lost, it will perfom the action
CKEDITOR.instances.editable.on( 'blur', function( e )
{

    //Right now this change is only client side, i would like to make it serverside
    $data = CKEDITOR.instances.editable.getData()
    $id = this.element.$.id
    document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML = $data
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you see, i commented the code so is well explained.
I have an id and i have a new data and i want the original HTML file modified.
Witch language should i use? Any particular library ?

I guess i need to use php

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad to answer in a simple StackOverflow answer, but the steps in an EXTREMELY terse list

1. Learn a server side language
2. Learn a Database
3. Extract the body from your HTML page to a server side page
4. Print the contents of the body from the database
5. Use AJAX or simple POST page where you can send the contents of the body
6. Learn enough JavaScript to send the body contents to your new page (AJAX or a generated form)
7. When your new page gets the HTML, save it to the database
8. Reload the page

Don't forget to sanitize your inputs!